# React - How to add a component to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I currently have a local React website (first project, so learning as I go) which has a select field that is pulling the options in from a database. That bit is fine. When I create a click function "onChange" to then get data from the database, this works fine.

My issue is that I want to be able to grab the data from the JSON data and append the data into a component. I currently have the following component set up, which works when I add this onto the page manually:

```
<QuotePhaseTitle title="Test Title" style="primary" />
```

So what I basically want to do is within the "onChange" function, get the data (which I can do easily enough) and then pass that to the "title" and "style" props. Once that has been passed, I then need to be able to return that data and input into the page somewhere.

Below is an example of the function so far (I am using WPAPI):

```
const quoteTypeChange = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const optionValue = e.target.value;
    try {
        await wp.quoteType().id(optionValue).then((data) => {
            const quoteTypeDetails = data;
            // Ideall want to pass in the <QuotePhaseTitle title="Test Title" style="primary" /> component, add in the data and then display that on the page //
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Error //
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Error //
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this? Sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: You can use state, and set it in your `quoteTypeChange`. Then pass the state value: `<QutotePhaseTitle title={titleFromTheStateSetInquoteTypeChange} style="primary"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The code itself doesn't "pass values to components", it doesn't really interact with components at all in general.  The code updates state.  The components use state.  So your component might define two state values, for example:

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('Test Title');
const [style, setStyle] = useState('primary');
```

And you would use that state in the JSX:

```
<QuotePhaseTitle title={title} style={style} />
```

Then all you need to do is update the state values:

```
wp.quoteType().id(optionValue).then((data) => {
  setTitle(data.someValue);
  setStyle(data.someOtherValue);
})
```

Structurally this is fundamental to React.  State drives display, logic updates state.

Comment: Thanks for your comment (and everyone else's) - wasn't sure who's best to reply to. That makes sense - I did go down the "useState" route at one point - but my issue lies in that the data that I am pulling out from WP and ACF varies. So on one of these posts it could have just one "QuotePhaseTitle" whereas the next might have 10 - so not sure how to achieve this, as it will vary. Any ideas?

Comment: @craigjoe: You can define and manage your state value however you like.  For example, if the state is a list of 1-many values then you can make it an array.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would do that for multiple instances?

Comment: @craigjoe: The description is a bit vague.  But if you want the state value to be an array, make it an array: `const [titles, setTitles] = useState(['Test Title']);`  And if you want to render a different UI element for each array element, in the rendering you'd map it: `{ titles.map(t => <QuotePhaseTitle title={t} />) }`

Comment: I hope this comment gives more context and is less vague. I basically have a JSON object being returned based on a WordPress post, using ACF. The ACF fields are for creating a quote - so it will have repeater fields for titles and quote elements, so there are numerous nested repeaters going on. I then need to output all of the fields in the order they appear in the admin, so could be the title then quote details, could be quote details x3 then title etc. The "QuotePhaseTitle" is basically part of a table. It's hard to explain. Anything I need to consider in addition to what you said?

Comment: @craigjoe: This sounds like it's getting further from the original question, which was just about how to use and update state in React.  If you have more complex data structures, you can debug and tinker with those data structures.  But the overall concept of state remains the same.  You can store values, arrays, and objects in state.  Go ahead and give it a try and see if you run into another specific issue, which can be a different Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks for your help David - I appreciate it. I am having a hard time articulating this, but I have created a new post which I hope is clearer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677683/react-usestate-and-mapping

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a state, so when the data comes from server, you put them on the state for example `this.setState({ title: data.title })` o using hooks `const [title, setTitle] = useState(); setState(data.title);`

And then pass the title value to your component: `<QuotePhaseTitle title={this.state.title} style="primary" />` of `<QuotePhaseTitle title={title} style="primary" />` if you are using hooks.

Also you can instantiate the hook value or the state with a default value.